# bootstrap asp.net text always shows on new row

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I have a listview on an ASP.net webform.  I want to have two columns on each row, the thing is, the second column always moves to a new line.  Here is my code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="aa" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-10">
                    Shows on first line/row
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-2">
                    shows on a new line
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Any link to the rendered page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this ?

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="aa" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
             
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                first line 1 
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    second line 1
                </div>
            </div>
              <div class="row">
       
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                first line 2
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6">
                    second line 2
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
</form>
```